# How do I unhide that Timeline event that says when I joined Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I accidentally hid the date I joined Facebook from my Timeline. How can I show it again?
It doesn't appear in my Timeline to change it and make it visible. I can't see it on my Activity Log (as hidden activity). What can I do to make it appear again?

Answer (score 1):

This is what was advised by the Facebook Community for [How do I unhide something previously hidden?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=641477339202593) at close to the time the above was posted:

> Go to your activity log on your profile and there choose "your posts". Scroll down to the post you want to 'unhide'. There will be a little barred circle next to it on the right side, click that and choose 'Allowed on timeline'. Done.

and a very little more recently (ibid.):

> On your FB page look at the top right side. There is the icon for settings...Click on 'Settings">> click on "activity log">>> on the left side click on "post you have hidden">>> scroll to that post>>> on the upper right side of the post there is a circular icon>>> click on the icon and then choose the option "allowed on timeline".

However it is probably different by now (eg **Posts You've Hidden** is more distinct, for the moment).